# A property of positive define matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, positive-definite

Consider the positive definite matrix $B_{m \times m}=\left(b_{i j}\right)$ has inverse $C=\left(c_{i j}\right)$. How to show that
$$
b_{i i}^{-1} \leq c_{i i}
$$
for $i \in\{1, \ldots, m\}$ with equality if and only if $b_{i j}=b_{j i}=0$ for all $j \neq i$.

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/324874/inverse-of-a-matrix-and-the-inverse-of-its-diagonals

Comment: @BrauerSuzuki Thanks. But the question you referred is seemed not the same as my question.

Comment: I know, I didn't flag as duplicate. There is a paper https://dml.cz/handle/10338.dmlcz/100600 which states this inequality as "well-known", unfortunately without reference

Comment: if you are familiar with majorization, this is equivalent to the simple inequality $1 \leq \big(\sum_{i=1}^n q_i \cdot x_i\big)\cdot\big(\sum_{i=1}^n q_i \cdot\frac{1}{ x_i}\big)$  where $x_i \gt 0$ and $q_i \geq 0$ and $\sum_{i=1}^n q_i = 1$ (i.e. effecting convex combinations)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $c_{ii}=B_{ii}/\det B$ where $B_{ii}$ is the $i$-th principal minor of $B$. Hence, the inequality is equivalent to $b_{ii}B_{ii}\ge \det B$. This follows from Fisher's inequality https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fischer%27s_inequality
The wikipedia proof can probably simplified in this particular case.

Comment: Got! Thank you very much!